# getChildren() not working for ViewStack in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

My Strucutre is like this.

```
<mx:ViewStack>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Form>
            <mx:FormItem>
    .
    .
    .
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Form>
            <mx:FormItem>   
</mx:ViewStack>
```

When I call the getChildren method on ViewStack, I only get the first HBox and not the others. How to get others as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to set the `creationPolicy` of the viewStack to `all`, otherwise as far as Flex is concerned it only has one child. Setting it to 'all' creates all the children up front.

You could also keep a int variable with the number of children, and if any are added, increment that variable. Then use viewStack.selectedItem = ? in your code.

Comment: Yes, this is common catch with ViewStack.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ViewStack` hides tabs other than selected one, they aren't returned with `getChildren()`. Try `numChildren` and `getChildAt()`, it should help.